# angular search by typing by select ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items, and need dynamically search that list by text, like:
I click the list and it opens, I can start typing the name of the item and the list will adjust the results.

```
items = [
{"id":1,"name":"AAA"},
{"id":2,"name":"BBB"},
{"id":3,"name":"CCC"},
{"id":4,"name":"DDD"}
]
```

So in that case starting typing "a" will show only the first row.

How can I achieve that? I tried to add an input type - text as a first row, but it did not help for me.
Here is my select

```
<select type="text" ng-model="item" ng-options="item as item.name 
for item in items></select>
```

I have also so methods and filter added, but it is not relevant for the problem.

Comment: did not understand?you  want to filter select field options based on input text?

Comment: Yes. But the input text has to be 1st option in select. Or, a "0" option.

Comment: maybe this is what you mean by searchable selects  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Answer (score -1):

If you want to search dynamically then you can use typeahead directive of angular-ui, you need to add its dependency in your app, in your case you can use following code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" typeahead="item as item.name for item in items | filter:{name:$viewValue}">
```

for more details on typeahead, check http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead